# Как отключить режим чтения для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как отключить режим чтения на сайте и возможно ли такое? На моем сайте не совсем корректно отображается режим чтения. Как отключить для пользователей возможность включать режим чтения на моем сайте? Спасибо

Comment: нет, программно это сделать нельзя

Comment: @ThisMan , Простите, не удержался, но подскажите если это нельзя сделать программно, то как это сделать аппаратно?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ну может не правильно выразился, то есть из кода js нельзя

Comment: @ThisMan А из Html можно или нельзя?

Comment: @AK оч толсто)))000